# Win 8 / 7 Dual Boot Nightmare

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, boot, bios

**I need help** as I don't have any knowledge about windows boot process, but I'm willing to learn.

Have an Acer Aspire V3-771 that came with Win8 preinstalled on 750GB HDD. Decided to try to use Dual Boot with Win8/7 combination.  Pulled Win 8 HDD added 1TB HDD and installed Win7 Pro. as single OS on new HDD.  Much to my surprise Acer has an extra HDD port for an additional HDD.

Installed additional HDD now machine will boot into Win 7 with BIOS changed from UEFI to Legacy and Security boot disabled.  System runs stably until shut down - then hangs with screen off but fan remains on until manually shutdown.

Problem: On reboot with BIOS changed back to UEFI and Secure Boot Win 8 will not boot, CD System disk will not boot and freezes with - BCD error 0x0000098.  **Any assistance will be appreciated.**

Comment: You will need to install Windows 8 while its in Legacy and with Secure Boot disabled,  The problem is the partition type more then likely.  Your only other option is to install Windows 7 with UEFI mode.

Comment: I have searched hundreds of forums never asked questions.   If I pull out win7 HDD and reinstall win7 using efi will that fix it? Thanks. Is there a way to save win7 updates and all the other additions I've made to it?  Thanks Again?

Comment: Nothing is guaranteed in life

Answer (score 1):

easy installation dual boot first create two drive C 100 GB and D 70 GB or higher as you wish 
first win 7 install on drive C after installation install win 8 on drive D same procedure but when windows ask you to where you copy windows file then select drive D ,

remember don't create every drive primary only two drive primary C and D and another drive are first extended then create logical drive ,,

if you create four or more primary drive then never install dual windows .

Comment: Can you apply this answer using 2 hdds Win 8 on one and win 7 pro on second drive?    Both are stable individually.  Do both need GPT partions or just on win 8 partiton?

Answer (score 0):

Start over (sorry).

Not sure what the point of having dual-drives & putting an OS on each...You'd get better performance with Win8 on the faster of the two HDD's. Then, change location of your user folders to the other HDD. Keep only Windows 8 & programs on drive 1).

Next, create a VM with 7 as guest. Virtualbox should do the job fine. VM also gets stored on drive 2) with your user folders.

Drive 1) stays clean & un-fragmented (as it becomes basically read-only from now on), drive 2) holds your data in case of OS corruption on drive 1).

Imho.  Good luck!